# can anyone please tell me what wrong in my code, it's shows (SyntaxError: invalid syntax)?

Tags: python

```
import math
import numpy as np
def car2geod (Xp,Yp,Zp):
    r=math.sqrt(math.pow(Xp)+math.pow(Yp))
    sii=math.atan(Zp/r*math.sqrt(1-ecce2))
    phi=math.atan((Zp+(ecce2*b*math.pow(math.sin(sii),3))/(r-(ecce2*a*math.pow(math.cos(sii),3)))
    Rn=a/math.sqrt(1-(ecce2*math.pow(math.sin(phi)))) 
    lam= math.atan(Yp/Xp)
    h=(r/math.cos(phi))-Rn 
    return phi,lam,h
```

Comment: Post the full error message; it usually points you to *where* the problem is. It's probably mismatched parentheses. This code is clearly wrong in other ways though, e.g. passing only single arguments to `math.pow`. A note: `math.pow` is *useless*; just use `**` and make more readable code. The `pow` built-in function is useful in three-arg form, but `math.pow` is 100% garbage.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you’re missing a closing parenthesis. `phi=math.atan((Zp+(ecce2*b*math.pow(math.sin(sii),3))/(r-(ecce2*a*math.pow(math.cos(sii),3))))` should do.